Python Dictionaries
hoping you all can help. I am having a bit of trouble wrapping my head around importing a text file into a python dictionary.
As an overview of my program, I am trying to take a text file (basicaly a CSV, but with a txt extention)
Sample data from text file:
Cessna,234.1
Velocity,412.5
Beechcraft,467.2
Gulfstream,599.3 
Honda,412.1
Velocity,398.8
Velocity,343.9
Gulfstream,630.2
Honda,456.3
Cessna,221.3
Velocity,405.2
Honda,436.4

The final product I am hoping for is to combine like aircraft, for example Honda would be Honda: (3,1304.8) in the dictionary. Honda being the key, 3 is the number of like aircraft in the text file, 1304.8 bing total mile between all Honda aircraft.
This is the code i am using to read the text file into a list (print is just me looking at what my code is doing)
aircraft = []
aircraftDict = {}

infile = open(file, "r")
for item in infile:
    item = item.rstrip()
    aircraft.append(item)
    
print (aircraft)

infile.close()

I have no issues with reading a file into a list, this is my result as a list:
['Cessna,234.1', 'Velocity,412.5', 'Beechcraft,467.2', 'Gulfstream,599.3', 'Honda,412.1', 'Velocity,398.8', 'Velocity,343.9', 'Gulfstream,630.2', 'Honda,456.3', 'Cessna,221.3', 'Camry,4.2', 'Honda,436.4']

All is good here, data looks good.
I have two questions:
One: how do I combine the list items and get Honda, 1304.8
Two: more importantly, how do I create a dictionary out of the combined data with a tuple. For example:
{"Honda":(3,1304.8), next aircraft here} 

Again, the final dictionary would be: Aircraft Type:(Number of Aircraft, Mile total from all like aircraft)

See https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader

Thanks, I have been digging all day, this is helpful!!!! Also, i have experience in other languages, this is my second week learning Python, aviation is my hobby

Here's how I would do it
with open("aircraft_data.txt", "r") as infile:
    for line in infile:
        # Split the line into aircraft type and mileage
        aircraft, mileage = line.strip().split(",")
        mileage = float(mileage)  # Convert mileage to a float

        # If the aircraft is already in the dictionary, update its count and mileage
        if aircraft in aircraft_dict:
            count, total_mileage = aircraft_dict[aircraft]
            aircraft_dict[aircraft] = (count + 1, total_mileage + mileage)
        else:
            # If the aircraft is not in the dictionary, add it with initial values
            aircraft_dict[aircraft] = (1, mileage)


Kurt, thank you, this place rocks,!!!

If you use a defaultdict, you won't have to check for the existence of the key, you will be simply able to run the code in the if block as if the key exists.

Yes that's a good point Abhijit!

You don't need to import any "helper" modules to do this.
You should always validate your source data. In this case a ValueError exception may arise if the 2nd token cannot be converted to float. The same exception may be raised if the number of comma-delimited tokens is not exactly two.
Therefore:
d: dict[str, tuple[int, float]] = {}

for row in open("data.txt"):
    try:
        k, v = row.split(",")
        if (t := d.get(k)) is not None:
            d[k] = t[0]+1, t[1] + float(v)
        else:
            d[k] = 1, float(v)
    except ValueError:
        pass # ignore invalid line

print(d)

Note:
It's not necessary to strip the input rows because float() is impervious to leading and trailing whitespace.

Assuming the lines from the file is read into an iterable separated by newlines (readlines),
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

tokens = [tuple(token.strip() for token in line.split(",")) for line in lines.split()]
tokens.sort()
result = {k: sum(float(v) for _, v in g) for k, g in groupby(tokens, key=itemgetter(0))}


{'Beechcraft': 467.2, 'Cessna': 455.4, 'Gulfstream': 1229.5, 'Honda': 1304.8, 'Velocity': 1560.4}

